# Show that there exists an $l$

Tags: number-theory

> Show that there exists an $l$ such that there exist prime numbers $p,q > 4k+3$ (for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$) such that \begin{aligned} 1+2l \equiv 0 \pmod{p},\\1-2l \equiv 0 \pmod{q}, \end{aligned}  and
>   \begin{aligned}1+2l &\not \equiv 0 \pmod{p^2},\\1-2l &\not \equiv 0 \pmod{q^2}.\end{aligned}

My book said to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but I didn't see how to use that here

Comment: What do you mean $p,q>4k+3$ for any integer $k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is oddly stated, so sorry if I missed the meaning.  It looks like we start with a given $k$.  Then choose two primes larger than $4k+3$.  Then I would use CRT to solve the system

\begin{aligned}1+2l & \equiv p \pmod{p^2},\\1-2l & \equiv q \pmod{q^2}.\end{aligned}

for $l$.  And this $l$ solves the first system.

Comment: How do we use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to solve that?

Comment: Since $p$ and $q$ are distinct odd primes, 2 has inverses mod $p^2$ and mod $q^2.$  The first congruence becomes $l\equiv (p-1)2^{-1} \pmod{p^2}$ and the second becomes $l\equiv (q-1)2^{-1} \pmod{q^2}$.  Then apply CRT as normal.

Comment: My book also says that $2l^2+2k+1$ is not divisible by $p$ because $p > 4k+3$. Why is that?

Comment: I dunno.  Normally, exercises say something like $p$ is of the form $4k+3$.  The inequality makes no sense.